# mapping a custom object to another object based on parameter value in C#

Tags: c#, class, object, mapping

I have a collection of source data in the below class format

```
public class TestData
{
    public int ParamId
    {
        get ;
        set ;
    }      

    public string ParamName
    {
        get ;
        set ;
    }      

    public string ParamValue
    {
         get ;
        set ;
    }     

    public string Category
    {
         get ;
        set ;
    }

    public string ReferenceId
    {
       get ;
        set ;
    }

    public string Info
    {
        get ;
        set ;
    }
```

I have couple of classes defined in my project say OrgGroup, EmpGroup. How can I extract some of the data from 'TestData' based on the ParamName and map it to either OrgGroup or EmpGroup?

For e.g., if ParamName='Network' then all property values of 'TestData' should be mapped to OrgGroup object else it should be mapped to EmpGroup

How can I achieve this in C#

Comment: What do you mean by mapping ? Do you mean that both of your classes (OrgGroup and EmpGroup) have the same property set ? If yes you can use inheritance. If they don't you will have to do it manually...

Comment: OrgGroup and EmpGroup have different property sets but Info is common

Comment: Then I don't understand... If the only property that they have in common is Info, just do it... `if (MyTestData.ParamName == "Network") { MyOrgGroup.Info = MyTestData.Info; } else { MyEmpGroup.Info = MyTestData.Info; }`